Twilio Studio Axios Error 400 when calling a function
I am following the instructions from this question Register Multiple Webhooks for a Single Twilio Number.
According to the Studio Flow logs: An incoming SMS message is received OK, but when the function runs, it returns this error:
Request URL: https://my-path-9999.twil.io/path_1
Request Method: POST
Response Status Code: 500
Response Content Type: text/plain

And for the flow data error:
"widgets": {
    "myfunction": {
      "status_code": 500,
      "content_type": "text/plain",
      "body": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400"

What I have done to solve the problem:

Ensured the function's dependencies were added (per the comments in the related post).
The only change to the related code, was the actual webhooks themselves.


Perhaps you should add some code to see your function and the request payload.

The function never worked.  I ditched this route and instead, created a new Studio Flow where the first webhook is a redirect, and the second is a http post after a 3 second delay with no response.  Because in my redirect, there is no response.  It's working out quite well!
